# How to deploy django with media files?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, django-media

I am trying to find a simple solution to deploy a django rest api which uses media files which are added via the admin panel. The rest api will be receiving very low traffic and so the simplest cheapest option is preferable.

Currently, I am using heroku, however when I add media files through the admin panel and come back to it later the files are no longer there.

Here is my `settings.py`:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '****'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['example.herokuapp.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'clothing',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle',
        'rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle'
    ),
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'anon': '400/day',
        'user': '500/day'
    }
}

ROOT_URLCONF = 'good_deal.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'good_deal.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Can django serve media files and do I need to change my database from SQLite to a PostgreSQL database to fix the problem or do I need to use something like Amazon S3?

Comment: Maybe take a look here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

Comment: Is this applicable for media files or only for static files. I think whitenoise is for static files which in my project work fine it's only the media files which get removed after a while.

Comment: hi tom. this is an advice: dont use sqlite database on production use postgre3 because the sqlite on production is a nightmare : )

Comment: Cheers, will do :)

Answer (score 0):

You *do* need to switch to Postgres, but this is a *different problem* to the one you ask about here, although they have the same underlying cause.

Heroku's file system is ephemeral and not shared between dynos. Anything stored there will be lost when you redeploy, or spin up extra processes. An sqlite db is stored as a file, so would be lost, which is why you need to use Postgres which is an external server.

But changing this won't help with your media files, as these have nothing to do with the database. Since they are *also* stored on the file system you need to use a different method of storage. Amazon's S3 is a good choice, as it is cheap and there are several third party libraries which integrate into Django.

Comment: do you have any good tutorials that I can follow to setup django and postgresql in production? Thanks

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration#database-configuration as a start.